# How do I access a digital camera drive via usb after safely removing it?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, devices

In Ubuntu 11.04, I unwisely right clicked and "safely unmounted the drive" of my Sony HDR-XR150 connected via USB. Now, when I plug my digital camera into my computer via USB, Ubuntu either doesn't register the new drive, or flashes the "recognition and choice of what to do with the USB drive" screen briefly.

Please help.

FYI, I ran `dmesg` with the following results:

```
    scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sony     Camcorder        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[   53.099590] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   53.101210] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 234413857 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
[   53.102473] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   53.102477] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[   53.103471] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[   53.103474] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   53.107097] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[   53.107101] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   53.452787]  sdb: sdb1
[   53.455391] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[   53.455393] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   53.455395] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   55.341231] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 5
[   55.590219] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[   55.870017] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
[   56.021458] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   56.186651] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 7
[   56.500014] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 8
[   56.651324] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   58.604859] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 8
[   58.920011] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[   59.270009] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[   59.400008] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   59.640013] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   59.870008] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
[   60.000008] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   60.240014] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   60.470014] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
[   60.890007] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[   61.010009] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 5
[   61.430007] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[   61.430016] hub 6-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[  180.320011] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 6
[  180.450016] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  180.690012] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  180.920010] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 7
[  181.050010] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  181.290035] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  181.520009] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 8
[  181.940007] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[  182.060015] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 9
[  182.480008] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[  182.480019] hub 6-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[  555.580012] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 10
[  555.710012] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  555.950010] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  556.180012] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 11
[  556.310009] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  556.550009] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  556.780009] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 12
[  557.200008] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[  557.320012] usb 6-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 13
[  557.740006] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 13, error -71
[  557.740016] hub 6-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could manually mount the camera: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: Please provide more than a link to an off-site man page. How does the user read the output of `dmesg` to figure out what device to `mount`? What would the `mount` command look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's been 7 years, still, I've just got this issue too The problem is lack of exFAT support. So, this should help:

```
sudo aptitude install exfat-fuse
```